# How to print the starting position of pattern in grep

Tags: grep

In python's regex (re) library I can do `re.search("<pattern>", string).start()` to get the start of the pattern (if pattern exists).

How can I do the same in the unix command line tool `grep`?

E.g. If **pattern**= "th.n" and the string is **"somethingwrong"**, I expect to see the number 5 (considering 1-based but 4 in a 0-based would be ok)

Thank you!

Comment: What's the expected input->output? I'm not sure I understood :)

Comment: @Ivan I would like to get a number that specifies the position of the starting character of the match. I will edit the question with an example. thx!

Comment: like if you look for `c` in `abcdefg` , you want it to return `3` ?

Comment: @Ivan yes. That's the case

Comment: 1) Can there be multiple matches? If so, what output do you want? 2) Does it have to be `grep`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Am I right in thinking that you want to do something that you can easily load in to an editor for highlighting?  If so, tell us more about that, because someone may have already done it.

Comment: @Sundeep, does not have to be grep... awk, sed, or other would be ok. I need to do it over all lines of a big file.

Comment: @AndyLester Long story short, I need these numbers over very long files. I can't do that by eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a Perl one-liner would be a happy medium between having to write a Python program and the simplicity of a standard Unix tool.

Given this file:

```
$ cat foo.txt
This thing
that thing
Not here
another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
thank you.
```

You could run this Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -lne'while(/th.n/g){print $.," ",$-[0]," ",$_;}' foo.txt
1 5 This thing
2 5 that thing
4 8 another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
4 45 another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
4 63 another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
5 0 thank you.
```

Also, the greplike search tool [ack](https://beyondgrep.com) (that I wrote)has a `--column` option to display the column:

```
$ ack th.n --column foo.txt /dev/null
foo.txt
1:6:This thing
2:6:that thing
4:9:another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
5:1:thank you.
```

Or with the `--nogroup` option so the filename appears on each line.

```
$ ack th.n --column --nogroup foo.txt /dev/null
foo.txt:1:6:This thing
foo.txt:2:6:that thing
foo.txt:4:9:another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
foo.txt:5:1:thank you.
```

I had to add the search of /dev/null because ack's output would be different if there was only one file being searched.

[ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) has a `--column` option, too.

```
$ rg --column --line-number th.n foo.txt
1:6:This thing
2:6:that thing
4:9:another thing way over here that has another thing and a third thing
5:1:thank you.
```

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
echo "abcdefghij" | grep -aob "e"
```

outputs :

```
4:e
```

Here:

-b to gets the byte offset

-a tells grep to use the input as text

-o outputs the findings

With your example:

```
echo ""somethingwrong"" | grep -aob "th.n"
4:thin
```

This works great on multiple matches:

```
echo "abcdefghiqsdqdqdfjjklqsdljkhqsdlf" | grep -aob "f"
5:f
16:f
32:f
```

Comment: maybe `-a ` is not necessary

Comment: The problem with `-b` is that it gives the the offset from the beginning of a file so you can't grep on every line. This is my mistake as I was not clear in the question that I need it to work iterating over all lines of a file